# Div Height property is not working properly in Chrome

Tags: html, css, height

In my `mvc` application I have added a `div` with `height:270px`.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .table-div {
        height: 270px;
        margin-top: -20px;
        border-top: 2px solid #DDD;
        border-bottom: 2px solid #DDD;
        margin-right: 10px;
        margin-left: 10px;
        background-color: white;
    }
</style>
```

Its working fine in `firefox`. But if I open it in `Chrome`, then its height will looks like more than `270px`. Why it is happening like this? How to solve this?

Comment: Are any other styles (like `box-sizing`) affecting the `div`?

Comment: @Mechanomorph : I am not using "box-sizing". I have added all the styles to the updated question. Have a look. Thanks.

Comment: If you are not using box-sizing the div will be 274px tall including the borders

Comment: I compared the `div` with the given css-styles in chrome and firefox, both heights are identical. What browser-versions are you using?

Answer (score 0):

May be it is the element height.border-top and border-bottom should be added with the 270.